# How to access outside data class property from inner enum class?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and got stuck on how to access an outside data class property from an inner enum class. Example code below on what I'm trying to do and the error message:

```
private data class MyClass(val num: Int) {

    val number: Int = this.num

    private enum class MyEnum(val elem: String) {
        VERTICAL("|"),
        HORIZONTAL("—"),
        NUMBERS((1..number).joinToString(" "))  //  <-- Unresolved reference: number
    }
}
```

Comment: _number_ is a property of an instance of _MyClass_, not of the class _MyClass_ itself.

Comment: Maybe you have the misunderstanding that an enum can be different for each instance of your class, but that’s not how it works. Enums are like constants and they have a single set of instances for all time. It doesn’t really make sense to pass the value of a non-constant property to the constructor of an enum.